# Historic Financial Data

Tags: curated-data, finance

The Mathematica line DateListPlot[FinancialData["L:ULVR", DatePlus[-1865]]]  does not work now. It generates  the output "DateListPlot::ntdt: The first argument to DateListPlot should be a list of pairs of dates and real values, a list of real values, or a list of several such lists". Does  FinancialData no longer hold the information. Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the output of the 'FinancialData' expression itself? Is that working first?

Comment: Please see [THIS](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/540228) for alternative.